# New gulp plugin: Correctly signaling completion

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

So I'm writing a new `gulp` plugin, which for the most part works, but somehow doesn't exit correctly and I've no idea why. For an easy reproduction, you can check it out locally from GitHub, install the dependencies and run the demo task: https://github.com/rbnlffl/gulp-rezzy.

But anywho, this is my plugin code:

```js
const through = require('through2').obj;
const sharp = require('sharp');
const log = require('fancy-log');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const File = require('vinyl');
const PluginError = require('plugin-error');
const pluginName = 'gulp-rezzy';

module.exports = (versions = []) => {
    return through(function(chunk, encoding, done) {
        versions.forEach((version, index) => {
            if (!version.suffix || !(version.width || version.height)) {
                this.emit('error', new PluginError(pluginName, 'Incorrect configuration!'));
            }

            const image = sharp(chunk.contents);
            image.resize(version.width, version.height);

            const promise = image.toBuffer();
            promise.then(buffer => {
                const file = new File({
                   cwd: chunk.cwd,
                   base: chunk.base,
                   path: chunk.path.replace(chunk.extname, '') + version.suffix + chunk.extname,
                   contents: buffer
               });

               this.push(file);
               log(`${pluginName}: ${file.relative} ${chalk.gray(`${Object.entries(version)}`)} ${chalk.green('✓')}`);

               if (index === versions.length -1) {
                    done();
               }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

And this is the output I get:

```
~/Sites/gulp-rezzy  yarn demo
yarn run v1.22.0
$ gulp demo
[12:16:37] Using gulpfile ~/Sites/gulp-rezzy/gulpfile.js
[12:16:37] Starting 'demo'...
[12:16:37] gulp-rezzy: annie-spratt-VtAy7t8zPz4-unsplash-sm.jpg width,500,suffix,-sm ✓
[12:16:37] gulp-rezzy: annie-spratt-VtAy7t8zPz4-unsplash-md.jpg width,1000,suffix,-md ✓
[12:16:37] gulp-rezzy: annie-spratt-VtAy7t8zPz4-unsplash-lg.jpg width,1500,suffix,-lg ✓
[12:16:37] gulp-rezzy: praewthida-k-0Tdvt8QZSAs-unsplash-sm.jpg width,500,suffix,-sm ✓
[12:16:37] gulp-rezzy: praewthida-k-0Tdvt8QZSAs-unsplash-md.jpg width,1000,suffix,-md ✓
[12:16:37] gulp-rezzy: praewthida-k-0Tdvt8QZSAs-unsplash-lg.jpg width,1500,suffix,-lg ✓
[12:16:37] The following tasks did not complete: demo
[12:16:37] Did you forget to signal async completion?
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
~/Sites/gulp-rezzy
```

I've tried everything from rewriting it with to a callback function completely without any promises, to using `Promise.all` after accumulating my images, refactoring it to use `async`/`await` but I always get the same result. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are sure the problem isn't in your `demo` task itself?  And not your plugin.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was in my task, sorry. I've forgotten to return the stream.